# Is it possible to limit the length of input in TextField (not JTextField)

Tags: java, user-interface

```
TextField tf3=new TextField("");
    tf3.setBackground(Color.pink);
    tf3.setForeground(Color.blue);
```

I need to put a limit in the length of the input..what should I do? Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int MAX_LEN = 10;

TextField.addDataChangeListener(new DataChangedListener() {

  public void dataChanged(int type, int index) {

    if(TextField.getText().length() > MAX_LEN ) {
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText().substring(0, MAX_LEN ));

  }
}
```

please refer to this [link](https://www.java.net/node/695975) for the actual page
hope this one would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BoundedTextField<D> extends TextField<D> {
@Override
public void setMaxLength(int m) {
    super.setMaxLength(m);
    if (rendered) {
        getInputEl().setElementAttribute("maxLength", m);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onRender(Element target, int index) {
    super.onRender(target, index);
    getInputEl().setElementAttribute("maxLength", getMaxLength());
}
```

}